# UICollectionView layout spacing between cells

Tags: storyboard, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

[image]

As you can see, there is a big gap between the first two cells on the top row. How can I eliminate this for this row and all other rows?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found the answer in [this great library: NHAlignmentFlowLayout!](https://github.com/nilsou/NHAlignmentFlowLayout)